# Why does QGIS save a QMD file when you export layer as KML?

Tags: qgis, file-formats, format

I was going to delete all the QMD  files but would like to know what they are for before I do in case there is a critical reason for the file(s) being produced.  I know they contain Metadata but what for and why?

Answer (score 4):

When a layer is exported to any file based layer format (except GeoPackage), the layer [metadata](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#metadata) are saved in a *.qmd file if the [Persist layer metadata](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#vector-specific-parameters) checkbox is checked in the "Save Vector Layer as..." dialog window.

Comment: Thank you, that explains why the file is created but I’d be interested to know why you would tick or untick “Persist layer metadata”.

Comment: @Vic, probably I don't understand exactly your question... It seems to me the answer is obvious: if you want to store the layer metadata (see what are the layer metadata at https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#metadata as already linked in the answer) to a file, you need the checkbox is ticked, otherwise not.

Comment: I was trying to say "Why" would you want to store metadata separately?  Also how would you use the qmd file?

Comment: @Vic, most of the layer formats cannot store the metadata, so they are normally stored in the QGIS project. If you export a layer that has associated metadata stored in the project and you want to also export such metadata, then you need to ensure the "Persist layer metadata" checkbox is ticked: the metadata associated to the layer will be saved to a *.qmd file since most of the layer formats cannot store the metadata (except for the GeoPackage format which can store the metadata). The metadata saved in a *.qmd file will be associated to the corresponding layer when imported in a QGIS project.

Comment: Understand now.